# Qualcomm Usb modem not detected

Tags: networking, 18.04, usb-modem

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 and wanted to use internet with my qualcomm usb modem it does'nt detect the modem but when i run 'lsusb' it brings this

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:1135 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05c6:1000 Qualcomm, Inc. Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've tried a method I saw here https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2074129

Here is the report for 'usb_modeswitch -W -v 05c6 -p 1000 -K'

```
Take all parameters from the command line
* usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
 * Version 2.5.2 (C) Josua Dietze 2017
 * Based on libusb1/libusbx

 ! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x05c6
DefaultProduct= 0x1000

StandardEject=1

Look for default devices ...
  found USB ID 1d6b:0003
  found USB ID 8087:0a2a
  found USB ID 5986:1135
  found USB ID 05c6:1000
   vendor ID matched
   product ID matched
  found USB ID 1d6b:0002
 Found devices in default mode (1)
Access device 006 on bus 001
Get the current device configuration ...
Current configuration number is 1
Use interface number 0
 with class 8
Use endpoints 0x01 (out) and 0x81 (in)

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
     Product: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
  Serial No.: 351602000025260
-------------------------
Sending standard EJECT sequence
Looking for active drivers ...
Set up interface 0
Use endpoint 0x01 for message sending ...
Trying to send message 1 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 1 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 0
Trying to send message 2 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 OK, message successfully sent
Read the response to message 2 (CSW) ...
 Response successfully read (13 bytes), status 0
Trying to send message 3 to endpoint 0x01 ...
 Device seems to have vanished right after sending. Good.
 Device is gone, skip any further commands
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye!
```

Comment: What reports `usb_modeswitch -W -v 05c6 -p 1000 -K` please add it to your question.

Comment: @nobody i've edited the question

Comment: After running the command then irun 'lsusb' it brings '    Bus 001 Device 010: ID 05c6:6000 Qualcomm, Inc. Siemens SG75 '  but after unpluging the modem and pluging it back it brings the mass storage after running ' lsusb'

Comment: I guess a udev rule is needed. Does the modem work after the command?

Comment: yes this was only a test.  @Rasheed use my command again and try to connect with this modem.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little udev magic.

create

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/90-qualcomm.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", ATTR{idProduct}=="1000", RUN+="/usr/sbin/usb_modeswitch -W -v 05c6 -p 1000 -K"
```

Let udev reload the roules.

P.S. fixing wrong file name

```
sudo udevadm  control -R
```

Replug the modem.

[found udev-rule](https://gist.github.com/UedaTakeyuki/07e0c6ca8df540028accc4186e3c6149)

Comment: Thanks very much its works after creating the udev rule