# Device "/dev/ttyUSB0" suddenly missing

Tags: usb, modem

I have a very basic server Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on Proxmox running Docker with a USB 3G Modem used as a SMS Gateway. It worked for a couple of weeks, but today it stopped working as device "/dev/ttyUSB0".
I didn't installed nothing recently, maybe I just upgraded the OS, but the device is seen on `dmesg` once I connect it:

```
[  290.515190] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  290.668094] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  290.668104] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
[  290.668107] usb 2-1: Product: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
[  290.668109] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
[  290.668111] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 35***********60
[  290.684334] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  290.686380] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[  290.686555] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  290.691327] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
```

And after some time:

```
[  312.783760] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  359.157508] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  359.157528] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  364.179931] usbcore: registered new interface driver qcserial
[  364.179957] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for Qualcomm USB modem
```

Here some other output:

```
# lsusb
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05c6:1000 Qualcomm, Inc. Mass Storage Device
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0627:0001 Adomax Technology Co., Ltd QEMU USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
# modprobe usbserial
# modprobe qcserial
#
```

I can reinstall the OS, and it would be the second time with the same issue, and if I don't find the root cause it may happen again. Does someone has any ideas of the root cause?

**UPDATE:**
Once replicating the behavior (connecting the USB device trough ProxMox), `journalctl -b` doesn't *seem* to show anything useful:

```
Apr 02 19:23:48 DOCKER-01 kernel: usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Apr 02 19:23:48 DOCKER-01 kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=1000, bcdDevice= 0.00
Apr 02 19:23:48 DOCKER-01 kernel: usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
Apr 02 19:23:48 DOCKER-01 kernel: usb 2-1: Product: Qualcomm CDMA Technologies MSM
Apr 02 19:23:48 DOCKER-01 kernel: usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Qualcomm, Incorporated
Apr 02 19:23:48 DOCKER-01 kernel: usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 35***********60
Apr 02 19:23:48 DOCKER-01 kernel: usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 02 19:23:48 DOCKER-01 kernel: scsi host3: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
Apr 02 19:23:48 DOCKER-01 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Apr 02 19:23:48 DOCKER-01 kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Apr 02 19:23:53 DOCKER-01 systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\[REDACTED]-runc.LcuTxY.mount: Deactivated successfully.
Apr 02 19:24:10 DOCKER-01 kernel: usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Apr 02 19:24:45 DOCKER-01 systemd[1]: run-docker-runtime\[REDACTED]-runc.s4nLGm.mount: Deactivated successfully.
```

Then, `brltty` is not installed (and I have already checked):

```
# dpkg -l | grep brltty
#
```

**UPDATE**

Comment: Are there any messages in `journalctl -b` surrounding those kernel messages? In particular, when udev detects the device in its "storage" mode, it's supposed to invoke "usb_modeswitch" which then does some magic to switch it to "modem" mode; look for messages related to that.

Comment: Can you plug the device in an usb2 port? And for a long shot `dpkg -l | grep brltty ` please.

Comment: Device may also be going bad can you replace it?

Comment: On Windows, it seems working.

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by following those instructions:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1295507/1685859
That doesn't explain why it was working for weeks without the UDEV rule, but it's fine it's fixed now.